# should complex types or anonymous types be used in jaxb/xsd mapping

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb

Long story short : when mapping XML, is it better to have complex types and thus multiple top-level classes or just anonymous types and thus hierarchies of inner classes?

Long story : I am in a fortunate position to have the schema the way i like it. I tried both approaches with eclipse and XJC and discovered that the classes generated from a schema with complex types lead to an inexplicable ClassCastException on unmarshalling (i guess i did sth wrong but lacking experience with JAXB i cant put my finger on it yet). The anonymous type/inner classes approach works fine but seems "smelly" considering separation of concerns and reuse.

Bonus question : is there an obvious mistake inexperienced JAXB/XSD users make frequently WRT complex type mapping that is likely to result in a ClassCastException on unmarshalling?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to people that when possible they design their own object model and then add JAXB annotations to map it to XML.  JAXB's ability to generate an object model from an XML schema is a convenience mechanism.

If you wish to use class generation, both styles of schema are possible and valid.

WRT the ClassCastException, they usually out put the actual and expected classes.  To debug this issue I would need to see the annotations on the property the error is related to and if the type for the actual unmarshalled type has an @XmlRootElement or an @XmlElementDecl on the ObjectFactory.

It is also possible that your XML is not valid for your schema.  Try setting an instance of Schema on the unmarshalled to enable validation.

Comment: Thank you, very informative and detailed. The XSD and XML ale both valid. Ill look into the ClassCastException issue in more detail soon. I only have experienced it in test cases, where unfortunately no additional info is provided.